# How to initialize a Gem in Rails 3? How to register Template Handlers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

My gem works fine with Rails 2.3 (using Bundler) but I cannot get it loaded in Rails 3.

my_app/*Gemfile:*

```
 gem 'mygem', '>= 0.1.0', :path => '../mygem/'
```

I know that it is found because I managed to get it "working" once.

I've read between the lines of many blog posts and rails tickets that `rails/init.rb` is deprecated and a toplevel `init.rb` should be used that requires the main lib file. However, none of them gets executed unless I `require 'my_gem'`explicitly in my Rails app. This is how it looks like at the moment:

*mygem/init.rb`:*

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib', 'my_gem')
raise StandardError, "derailed!"
```

*mygem/lib/my_gem:*

```
require 'my_gem/template_handler'
raise StandardError, "derailed!"

module MyGem
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    raise StandardError, "derailed!"
    initializer "template handler registration" do
      raise StandardError, "derailed!"
      ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :act, TemplateHandler
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Template.register_template_handler :act, TemplateHandler
```

I cluttered everything with raise statements... the fact that none of them is raised makes me think that all my attempts to register my template handler have been in vain... ;)

I am running out of ideas to get my gem loaded. `my_gem/lib` is in the `$LOAD_PATH`, everything seems to be fine.

Comment: You seem to be inconsistant with 'mygem' and 'my-gem'. You might need :require => 'my_gem' ?

Comment: Wow, you are right. Post this as answer and I will accept it. (Do you also know how to register a template handler correctly?)

Comment: Now everything is consistent with underscore again. However, ::Rails.root is nil now and the loading process is aborted. How to load my gem after Rails?